# How to make menu similar to menu on linkedin.com

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wan't to make navigation bar like on linkedin.com. And I find some tutorials how to make it with html5, but as I see linked in doesn't use html 5 there. So can somebody point me to same guide how to make bar like that?
Is it necessary to use jQuery to make menu like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for the record: if some site doesn't use Html5 it doesn't mean you shouldn't ;)

LinkedIn uses JavaScript to build the menu. There are dozens of tutorials which handle dropdown menu's like this. Mostly it's the easiest way to use a framework like jQuery or MooTools, but of course it can also be done with 'regular' Javascript.

A few tutorials:

Using jQuery: http://www.narga.net/sexy-jquery-drop-down-multi-level-menu/

Using pure JavaScript:

- http://javascript-array.com/scripts/simple_drop_down_menu/
- http://www.scriptiny.com/2008/04/sliding-javascript-dropdown-menu/

Hope this helps