# How to make bootstrap navbar stable after zooming out browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists, navbar

I use bootstrap navbar component, here there is a problem when zooming out the browser. After zooming out, the li in navbar will overflow outside the navbar.

Is there any solution to make li won't overflow out of the navbar?   Like the navbar in http://www.linkedin.com/.

Comment: I can't find that problem, can you provide a fiddle/screenshot/instructions?

Answer (score 0):

Go over this  [Stack Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7118363/1557322) LinkedIn like menu (what linkedin is using)

Hope this helps