# How to change the color of status bar symbols (Carrier,wifi,Time)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, statusbar

I want to make linkedIn type menu button status bar symbols (Carrier,wifi,Time) appears in black. But i want to make it same like linkedIn in which status bar symbols is white and background is black.

But on a Particular ViewControllers View.

I’m using the imageView to make the background black.

But any one please suggest me the correct way to achieve this same as linkedIn.

Thanks In Advanced.

Comment: post the image of expected

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118275/how-to-make-menu-similar-to-menu-on-linkedin-com

Answer (score 4):

In iOS 7, there are two ways to change the status bar color:

**Per view controller**

Override the `preferredStatusBarStyle:` method and return `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`:

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle 
{ 
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
}
```

**Per app**

To change the color of the status bar in your entire app, add this code at initialisation time:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Then, open your project target in Xcode, click the Info tab, and set the "View controller-based status bar appearance" property to `NO`.

**Screenshot**

Here's a picture of the expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

there are two types for status bar

- UIStatusBarDefault: black text
- UIStatusBarLightContent: white text

Both of them have transparent background.

Found a nice introduction article on `StatusBar`: [evelopers-guide-to-the-ios-7-status-bar](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/developers-guide-to-the-ios-7-status-bar/)